# get unique machine id in python 2.7

Tags: python

```
import pycpuid    
b=pycpuid.cpuid(1)
pid=str(b[0]+b[3])
```

Is that the same every time system reboots? 
Not sure what passing different ints does to cpuid function?
ie: no matter what OS or version of that OS is installed, or network adapters...
if python is run and this function used, it will always return same value
thats what im looking for, based on the CPU, no other hardware

Comment: What do you intend to use this for?

Answer (score 2):

The [CPUID call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) will not be unique (but it won't change either - so it will be the same across OSes (it's an opcode implemented in the processor)) for a specific computer. Only [a subset of processors (in the Pentium 3 range for Intel and a few other brands)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX=3:_Processor_Serial_Number) returns an actual serial number. AMD does not return a serial number in any version.

The integer given to `cpuid` tells it [what information it should retrieve - see the EAX column in the documentation for the opcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#Calling_CPUID) - i.e. if it should return a specific check for a feature. You shouldn't have to call it directly, but instead use the helper functions defined in pycpuid (which gives arguments according to what it should retrieve).

If you're calling `cpuinfo` with an argument of `1`, you're [asking it to return the information given](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_45.html) when EAX is 1:

> INPUT EAX = 1: Returns Model, Family, Stepping Information
>   When CPUID executes with EAX set to 1, version information is returned in EAX.
>
> INPUT EAX = 1: Returns Additional Information in EBX
>
> When CPUID executes with EAX set to 1, additional information is returned to the EBX register: - Brand index (low byte of EBX) - this number provides an entry into a brand string table that contains brand strings for IA-32 processors. More information about this field is provided later in this section.
>
> CLFLUSH instruction cache line size (second byte of EBX)
>   this number indicates the size of the cache line flushed with CLFLUSH instruction in 8-byte increments. This field was introduced in the Pentium 4 processor.
>
> Local APIC ID (high byte of EBX)
>   this number is the 8-bit ID that is assigned to the local APIC on the processor during power up. This field was introduced in the Pentium 4 processor.

Comment: b[1] does change, that's why i dont use it, thanks for the info

Comment: Sure, when you're asking for information from the processor that can change (such as APIC assigned numbers, I'd guess), then you'll get variable results. But if you want a stable value, ask for stable values - but neither will give you an unique identifier of a computer (.. or of a specific CPU).

Answer (score 2):

Latest Linux versions come with auto-generated machine id which can be found at /etc/machine-id .

```
import os
machineId = os.popen("cat /etc/machine-id").read()
print(machineId)
```

[Ubuntu Documentation for Machine Id](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/machine-id.5.html)

[FreeDesktop Documentation for Machine Id](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html)

Comment: Can also just do `Path("/etc/machine-id").read_text().strip()`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the following code and syntax instead of pycpuid. I hope this helps.

```
#The following can be used to generate a random id
import uuid 

# Printing random id using uuid1() 
print ("The random id using uuid1() is : ",end="") 
print (uuid.uuid1()) 

#The following can be used to retrieve the MAC ADDRESS which is necessary for #the machine's specific ID

from uuid import getnode as get_mac
mac = get_mac()

#Prevents spoofing of MAC ADDRESS
>>> print uuid.getnode.__doc__
Get the hardware address as a 48-bit positive integer.

    The first time this runs, it may launch a separate program, which could
    be quite slow.  If all attempts to obtain the hardware address fail, we
    choose a random 48-bit number with its eighth bit set to 1 as recommended
    in RFC 4122.
```

Comment: if you would like to achieve a constant ID for a particular machine then you should be using the MAC Address of the machine. I will post the code above. Please upvote the solution if it is conducive to your situation. This solution is also cross platform.

Comment: I explained better in edited question, does that help? mac address are easily spoofed, but i've never heard of cpu spoofing.

Comment: I edited my answer with the solution, please let me know if that works.

Comment: A MAC address also identifies a *network interface*, not a machine. A machine can have multiple MAC addresses associated with it.

Comment: I can add code to your solution to counter spoofing of a MAC ADDRESS. This is a fool proof solution to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

On linux machines, the convention is to read `/etc/machine-id`. Which is a randomly generated id.